# Debian 9.4 Installer - Black Screen after selecting an installation option

Tags: linux, boot, debian, installer

I boot from an USB-stick, select the installation method an the screens turns black. If I pick one of the "speech" options, the screen also turns black but I can hear the installation instructions. So the root cause is about the black screen. I have read about parameters, e.g. vga=normal and such which can be set.

However, I'm not sure where exactly to place them.
I try to run the installation on a Huawei Matebook X Pro wich has an intel UHD 620 and nvidia MX150 graphic card. 
Secure boot is off. I also tested the Ubuntu and FreeBSD installer. These two work and I can proceed with the installation.